# VMWare REST Api - Get information about VM by ip address using PHP

Tags: php, ip-address

I'm using the VMWare REST API (`/api/vcenter/host`) to query information about the VM Hosts registered on a vCenter. I would like to get the name of the VM if I search for the IP address and also the other way around, search for the name of the VM by the IP address.

[image]

I already get this information, if i search for the information using the VM name:

[image]

but using the IP address to get this same information doesn't work.

Comment: Paste text, not images!

Answer (score 0):

This information (plain IP address[es]) is/are not currently available from the REST API though it *was* planned some time ago. As many VMs today have multiple adresses (think of IPv6 alone) and the API is not able to return multiple values with mixed types, it would be not easy to implement.

You can use the management SDK or one of the VMOMI (VMware Managed Object Management Interface). There are multiple SDKs available for several languages on GitHub (pyvmomi, govmomi, and rbvmomi) to get the adresses.

Update: Found the link (from 2018) at https://github.com/vmware-archive/vsphere-automation-sdk-rest/issues/21

Answer (score 0):

Here is the PHP implementation that worked for me, in order to be able to search for MAC address and IP address information of the researched virtual machine:

```php
function getIpAddress($vm, $server, $id) {
    $key = "power_state";
    if (isset($vm[$key])) {
        $vmid = $vm['vm'];
        // echo $vmid;
        $url = "https://$server/api/vcenter/vm/$vmid/guest/networking/interfaces";
        // echo $url;
        $ch = curl_init();
        // curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); 
        $headers = array(
            'Accept: application/json',
            'Content-Type: application/json',
            "vmware-api-session-id: $id"
         );
        // echo $id;
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        $result = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);
        if (! $result) {
            return false;
        }

        $teste = json_decode($result, true);

        echo '<form method="post" action="dvlindex.php">';
        echo '<ul>';
        echo '<li><h4>Mac Address: ' . $teste[0]['mac_address'] . ' </h4></li>';
        echo '<li><h4>IP Address: ' . $teste[0]['ip']['ip_addresses'][0]['ip_address'] . ' </h4></li>';
        echo "</form>";
    }
}
```